# SAPUI5 Function import with Date

Tags: date, odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

I have the following problem.
I have an Function import where I have two date fields.
[SEGW Function import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTScF.png)

here is how i call the function import:

```
        this.getView().getModel("odata").callFunction("/SavePos", {
            method: "GET",
            urlParameters: oProperty,
            success: function(oData, response) {
                jQuery.sap.delayedCall(500, this, function() {
                    this.getView().byId("idI_HuCount").focus();
                }); 
                sap.m.MessageToast.show(this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("DATA_SAVED"));
                this.setBusy(false);
            }.bind(this), // callback function for success
            error: function(oError) {
                sap.m.MessageToast.show(this.getErrorMessageFromOdataError(oError));
                this.setBusy(false);
            }.bind(this)
        });
```

If i enter the dates, everything works fine.
But in a few cases i don't have to input any date.
If i don't enter any date i get the following error message in gateway:
Invalid function import parameter
[OData Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r16PD.png)

If i add the date Property as emtpy (oProperty.ProdDate = "";) then i get this error message:
Deformed URI literal syntax
[OData error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcETt.png)

Do you have an idea how i can call the function import with empty date fields?

EDIT: 
Here is how the request looks like if i set the date field to "":

```
GET SavePos?sap-client=200&Docno='00000000000000000000000410000003293'&Itemno='0000000020'&HuTopTyp='E1'&QuanTopHu=2m&Productid=guid'005056bc-ebf7-1eda-81aa-812468f4d0ee'&QuanProHu=5m&HuSubTyp='%20'&QuanSubHu=0m&Sample=''&ProdDate=&BestBeforeDate=
```

And like this if i don't set any values:

```
GET SavePos?sap-client=200&Docno='00000000000000000000000410000003293'&Itemno='0000000020'&HuTopTyp='E1'&QuanTopHu=2m&Productid=guid'005056bc-ebf7-1eda-81aa-812468f4d0ee'&QuanProHu=5m&HuSubTyp='%20'&QuanSubHu=0m&Sample=''
```

Comment: pass null as default value and check.

Comment: @santosh: i already tried undefined and null and both did not work.

Comment: Thanks Marc i used this as a workaround but i thougth there have to be a better option.

Comment: I found this answer in a blog post. Seems like the column `NULLABLE` is simply hidden for FunctionImports but can be made visible: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/14/implementing-optional-parameters-in-the-function-import/#comment-480658

Comment: thanks marc. I found the same and postet the answer but i gets deletet by Admin?